# how to adjust the picture when using CircleAvatar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I was trying to insert a image(circular) using a CircleAvatar widget.but when i choose a desired size for the widget it crops down the photo.Now the issue is that it crops down the face part,so i want to scroll up the picture so that other useless part of photo can be cropped..I'm a newbie in flutter.Any help is appreciated.

Part of the code-

```
body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/mine.JPG'),
                    radius: 90,
                  ),//circle avatar
                ),//container
              ),//center
              Text(
                'Gaurav Arora',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 40,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

ClipOver widget will help you out to adjust your image within the circle avatar.

```html
ClipOval(
  child: Image.network(
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
),
```

Comment: It didn't help really .it just fitted the image's important parts according to our width and height.I wanted to crop out the lower body and just keep the upper body in the picture.Maybe i should just try cropping the picture first and then using these widgets.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the child attribute instead of backgroundImage.

```
CircleAvatar(
  child: FittedBox(
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter, 
    fit: BoxFit.cover, 
    child: AssetImage(...)
  ),
  ...
)
```

Comment: this will not let the image be circular, like the backgroundImage attribute